# How to check if it's more that 2 days in the past not the future?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to check if the date is more that or equals 2 days in the past only , But it also works if it's in the future.

Here is the code:

```
$d = new DateTime('04-06-2018');

$todayDate = new DateTime();

$interval = $d->diff($todayDate);

$days = $interval->format('%a');

if($days >= 2)
{echo 'true'; }
else
{echo 'false';}
```

It returns true whenever the difference between the two dates is more that or equals 2 , How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking `invert` property in your `DateInterval`.

```
$d = new DateTime('3-04-2018');
$todayDate = new DateTime();
$interval = $d->diff($todayDate);

if($interval->format('%a') >= 2
    && 0 === $interval->invert
) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the if to check if date is in the past:

```
if($days >= 2 && strtotime($d) < time())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to acheive this

return $interval->format("%r%a");

Cast to int if needed:

return (int)$interval->format("%r%a");

Here you will get positive and negative number to check future and past date.

Hope it helps